# Reference help: asymptotic reducibility of systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

I was reading a paper about the reducibility of linear functional differential equations with quasi periodic coefficients. The paper talks about the **asymptotic reducibility of systems.** I don't the definition of  asymptotic reducibility of system. Could someone tell me the definition of that and give me a good reference to get more  about it ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the paper, usually in that kind of problems reducibility means that you may find a change of coordinate that put your system in an other one whose coefficients are time independent. Asymptotic I can image that they are not able to find a change of coordinates that tranform your system in an other one whose coefficients are time independent, but maybe they are able to find $n$ transformation such that the first $n$ term of  are time independent. But you always have a time dependent remainder. Maybe if you link the paper I try to understand.